# Parsing error: Missing semicolon in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to implement a rich text editor in Vue.js for a learning purpose. I've been following approach here:  
https://roe.dev/blog/building-your-own-vue-rich-text-component

But I'm receiving an error while loading my localhost page. 
[image]

Is my code missing something? Here are crucial parts:

App.vue ->

```
<template>
   <div><Richinput/></div>
</template> 
<script>
import Richinput from './components/Richinput.vue'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {

   Richinput
  }
}
</script>
```

RichInput.vue ->

```
<template>
  <div contenteditable @input="handleInput" @keydown="handleKeydown" />
</template>

<script lang="ts">
const exec = (command: string, value?: string) =>
  document.execCommand(command, false, value);

const queryCommandValue = (command: string) =>
  document.queryCommandValue(command);

export default {
  props: {
    value: { type: String, default: "" },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$el.innerHTML = this.value;
  },

  watch: {
    value(newValue) {
      if (this.$el.innerHTML !== newValue) this.$el.innerHTML = newValue;
    },
  },
  methods: {

    handleInput(e: InputEvent | KeyboardEvent) {
      const { firstChild } = e.target as HTMLElement;

      if (firstChild && firstChild.nodeType === 3) exec("formatBlock", "<p>");
      else if (this.$el.innerHTML === "<br>") this.$el.innerHTML = "";

      this.$emit("input", this.$el.innerHTML);
    },

    handleDelayedInput(e: KeyboardEvent) {
      this.$nextTick(() => this.handleInput(e));
    },
  },
  handleKeydown(e: KeyboardEvent) {
    if (
      e.key.toLowerCase() === "enter" &&
      queryCommandValue("formatBlock") === "blockquote"
    ) {
      this.$nextTick(() => exec("formatBlock", "<p>"));
    } else if (e.ctrlKey) {
      switch (e.key.toLowerCase()) {
        case "b":
          e.preventDefault();
          this.$nextTick(() => exec("bold"));
          break;

        case "i":
          e.preventDefault();
          this.$nextTick(() => exec("italic"));
          break;

        case "u":
          e.preventDefault();
          this.$nextTick(() => exec("underline"));
          break;

        default:
          break;
      }
    }
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Your code is written in TypeScript and it needs to be compiled to JS, because browsers do not understand the TypeScript syntax. Are you using some kind of bundler/build process?

Comment: I have no idea. I just created an empty project with Vue create (terminal) and copied those elements. What should I do to fix it then?

Comment: You need to compile the code. If you're using VueCLI to set up the project, are you sure you chose the TypeScript option? Chances are you didn't... might want to go through the setup process again.

Comment: I did not, where I can reset this to TS then?

Comment: Run the setup again using VueCLI. You probably just hit ENTER all the way through, and selected the default JS option (instead of TS)

Comment: You mean I have to create a new project once again in VS code? Or what to do exactly?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235625/discussion-between-yras8-and-terry).

Comment: https://cli.vuejs.org/core-plugins/typescript.html#installing-in-an-already-created-project